# Slide to delete a record from a tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an editable `tableView`. when i click on the `bar button` the table becomes editable (a `delete` button will appear in front of each `cell`).

When i also slide a `cell` in the `tableview`, the delete button gets displayed. I need to know the method that gets executed when i slide to the `cell` to `delete` the record of that `cell`.

I am hoping to change the `Edit` `barbutton` to `done` when the user slides the cell. So how can i do this programatically.

Sorry and i don't have any code to demonstrate.

Comment: Have you looked at apples coredatarecipes?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the most complex project example i found. (may be because i am a beginner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the line you need to add in `viewDidLoad` to add **edit** button which gets converted to **Done** when you touch it.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

This is the description for `editButtonItem`:
**Returns a bar button item that toggles its title and associated state between Edit and Done.**

This is the DataSource method which gets called when you Click `Edit`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{

    // Delete code goes here. This is from Core data sample code to delete record. You can implement your own code here.

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }

 }   

}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can respond to the delete button appearing as a UITableViewCell

- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {

  if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) {
      NSLog(@"We're showing the delete button");
  }
  }

Here's the link to the class reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am already using the above method. But i have no clue where should i add the barbutton which says `Done`. Should i add it inside the `commitEditingStyle` ?

Comment: inside the if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) happens when the user taps on the delete button. I'm not quite sure why you would want to create another step for your user. It might be better to just dismiss the view that you have automatically.

Comment: in the iPhone's `Phone` app, this hapence when you are trying to delete a number of a contact. you could `slide` a cell to delete or click on the `delete bar` button.